# safari - contenteditable, after making it empty, creates an element with text-align:center

Tags: safari, contenteditable

In safari,

i had a simple edtable div with a input button, on deletion of the element (backspace or delete), caret moves to center of edtiable div with some inline styled p tag with text-align:center and inline style "color"

`<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
       <input type="button" value="inputBtn" />
    </div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/VqCvt/

its a strange behavior observed only in safari.

Comment: Confirmed. What problem do you need to solve?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791. These bugs appear in dozens of cases and require handling backspace in a custom way (hard) or doing post-fixes with Mutation Observers.

Comment: Over a year later and this is still a problem.  Well done Apple!   It appears to be directly tied to the input tag.   The markup always seems to resemble the style of the input element that was removed. I haven't found a work around yet, but I will edit my post if I find something.

Answer (score 3):

Over a year after this post, this issue is still a problem.  This issue is directly tied to the `input` tag.  Once an `input` tag has been in a `contenteditable` element, Safari will attempt to make the style of the text similar to the input (I confirmed this by observing that the resulting style was different for `type="text"` vs `type="button"`).  It's a very strange bug.  I have found a workaround that works, but it's pretty absurd.  My fix is basically to test when my main input no longer has content, and then removing the element, and re-adding it

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div contenteditable="true" id="content" role="textbox"></div>
</div>
```

and in my "keyup" listener, I put the following code

```
// Grab main editable content div
var element = document.getElementById("content");

// Check empty state conditions.  These work for me, but you may have your own conditions.
if (element.getElementsByTagName("input").length == 0 &&
        element.innerText.trim().length == 0) {
    // Grab parent container
    var elementContainer = document.getElementById("content-wrapper");

    // Add a copy of your element to the same specifications.  If you have custom style attributes that you set through javascript, don't forget to copy them over
    elementContainer.innerHTML = '<div contenteditable="true" id="content" role="textbox"></div>';

    // Re-focus the element so the user doesn't have to click again to keep typing
    element = document.getElementById("content");
    element.focus();
}
```

What this code does works for my case because `input` is the only elements which are allowed in my code other than `text` nodes and `<br>`, so I first check to make sure there are no `input` elements, and then make sure the innerText is empty (this indicates no content in my case, you may have to customize your conditions for the "empty" state).  Once the empty state is confirmed, I replace the old div with a new one to the same specification, and the user never notices.  A very strange issue with a hacky workaround, but I think `contenteditables`.

You could probably also strip out the HTML that Safari is generating, but for my case this solution is much simpler.  I hope this helps someone in the future.