# javascript .length.toString not measuring correctly

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, contenteditable

**Environment:** OS X 10.12.6, Safari 11.0.1

I have a contenteditable div, and I'm using `onkeyup` to display how many characters are in the div in a span elsewhere on the page. In the function called by the div's `onkeyup=fn()`, I have this:

```
var oj = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var co = oj.innerText;
var le = co.length.toString();
var sp = document.getElementById("myspan");
sp.innerHTML = le;
```

So say I have 5 characters typed into the div, for instance `abcde`; I get five in the span - as you would expect. As I backspace, it counts down correctly:

```
4, 3, 2, 1...
```

But when I backspace over the last character, `a`, instead of going from one to zero... the result stays at one. I see this:

```
         +-------- // Everything here and previous is correct
         |  +----- // Still correct, there's still an a in there
         |  |  +-- // This is incorrect - the div is now empty
         |  |  |
5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1
a  a  a  a  a
b  b  b  b
c  c  c
d  d
e
```

Likewise, when I type `abcde` at that point again, the count stays at one for empty, *still* stays at one for the `a`, and *then* proceeds upwards with...

```
2, 3, 4, 5
```

...thereby showing one twice: Once when empty, and once when there is actually one character in the div:

```
+-------- // div is empty here - this is wrong
|  +----- // div actually has one character here
|  |  +-- // and this and following are all correct
|  |  |
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
   a  a  a  a  a
      b  b  b  b
         c  c  c
            d  d
               e
```

There are no errors in the javascript console, and code past this is definitely executing, so the Javascript machine hasn't simply choked.

I expected to get zero. Why do I get this result?

Comment: Do you have this in a fiddle?

Comment: Please `console.log(JSON.stringify(co))` to see what's going on. Probably a contenteditable is never cleared but always retains an invisible character

Comment: does it ever get back to zero or always stay at one?

Comment: Backspace issue? Safari is known to insert an empty `<p></p>` with some style stuff added to it in content editable. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24848900/125981

Comment: @bergi, I used `console.log(JSON.stringify(co))` as suggested (and thank you for that.). It shows that there is a `\n` remaining after the last backspace. Which is bizarre. There wasn't one in there in the first place, and the `<div>` is written as `<div></div>` with no content at all. **And** it goes away when the first character is typed. Looks like a Safari bug to me, unless there's some further rationale to this.

Comment: @daniel-gail, I have it on a [web page](http://ourtimelines.com/aamacropreview.html)

Comment: @fyngyrz What happens if you press Enter in the empty div? If it's distinguishable from `\n`, you can use `len = (co == '\n' ? 0 /* Safari */: co.length)` to work around this behaviour

Comment: @bergi, it shows two `\n` characters. So yeah, I could work around it. This is where I begin to rant. :)

Comment: @joey, no, never goes back to zero due to the count. Once it's had content, it always carries that (as it turns out) specious `\n` around. @younel's snippet does the same thing.

Comment: The reason for this is that Safari appears to convert block elements to the newline (empty div is a block) when empty - which is what you appear to be seeing. i.e. innerText is a property that represents the "rendered" text content thus the new line.